# Error: Cron Not Running

Tags: drupal, cron-job, cron, drush

For several months we have been seeing the error "Cron Not Running". I have repeatedly configured crontab for the `root` user, and currently have the following:

```
0 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 https://<redacted>/cron.php?cron_key=<redacted>
0 * * * * drush -r /var/www/html/drupal -l https://<redacted> civicrm-api -u <redacted> job.execute
```

I have followed the [Managing Scheduled Jobs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs) documentation each time, but still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

What might I check to make sure Cron is configured correctly?

Comment: This issue has affected us for many months. I have tried several solutions, and it won't go away.

Answer (score 2):

I may have solved this with the following steps.

1. create a drush alias for the site
2. configure crontab using the drush alias

## Drush alias (~/.drush/example.aliases.drushrc.php)

```
<?php

    $aliases['example.com'] = array (
        'uri' => 'example.com',
        'root' => '/path/to/drupal',
    );

?>
```

## Crontab

```
0 * * * * drush -u 1 @example.com civicrm-api job.execute auth=0 --out=json
```

Comment: See also: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/136722/drupal-7-cron-does-not-run-civicrm-scheduled-jobs

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Cpanel,  including the wget:

wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://mysite.org/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=myusername&pass=mypassword&key=123456789abcdefg'

Note the single quotation marks at start and end of syntax - after wget string

Comment: On mine it was necessary to add the path to wget. Cron had no default paths associated with it.

Comment: My cron is running in Cpanel without -O - -q -t 1 - what is "O - -q -t 1"?

Comment: Please refer to the wget manual on
https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Option-Syntax